# Guidance needed on a real analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation

Few years ago when I was in graduation I read a book that was very well written . This book dealt with the misconceptions that students generally have in real analysis and overall mathematics. It stated the misconceptions and then showed why that was wrong. Also it emphasid on key words. Like what will happen in such a problem when the word continuity is dropped for instance what will happen if this function is periodic. And all such kind of things

I don't remember the name of the book now

Can someone help me . If they know any book similar of this.

Thanks in advance this will be a great help.

Comment: Is this it? https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221665189_Ten_Misconceptions_from_the_History_of_Analysis_and_Their_Debunking

Answer (score 1):

Grinberg's book (below) is not the book you're looking for, because it was published in 2017, but Grinberg's book seems roughly similar to what you're asking for:

Raffi Grinberg, [**The Real Analysis Lifesaver**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691172935), Princeton University Press, 2017, iv + 193 pages.